# How do you compare values in a database and a flat file in Java?

Tags: java, database, oracle, flat-file

I have a flat file that is pipe delimited and an database table.  I would like to create a 2nd flat file that contains all the differences between the flat file and the database.

An example would be if there exists entries in the database that do not exist in the flat file the entire row would be printed in the 2nd flat file (there will never be an entry in the flat file that is not in the database).  Another example would be if the rows are similar but there is a difference in a field then the database entry would be printed in the flat file.

The best way I can think to do this is to create 2 two-dimensional arrays containing the data from the flat file and the database, if the primary key does not exist in the flat file array then print out the results from a select statement.  If the primary key does exist but the other fields do not exist then print out the results from a select statement.  This is the best thing i can think of, however it seems inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?  I am using Java to do this.

Comment: Most databases have functionality to read files directly -- the entire operation could be done from SQL, and would scale better than an application language.

Comment: What data volumes are you talking and is the source file ordered ? I'd tend towards a SQL/external table solution if the flat file is accessible from the DB. If the data volumes are trivial, java could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already comparing against a database, why not just do it all in SQL? Upload the contents of the file into the database, find the two complements (A minus B and B minus A) and export to another file. Something like:

```
SPOOL diff.txt
SELECT * FROM flatfile_table
MINUS
SELECT * FROM db_table
UNION
SELECT * FROM db_table
MINUS
SELECT * FROM flatfile_table
ORDER BY SortCriteria;
SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

in oracle you can create external table from file [tutorial for external tables](http://www.orafaq.com/node/848)

then create simple select that will build diff between your data and then simply export

Answer (score 0):

Write Java program which gets data from database into *another* flat file in the same format as the file you already have.

Make sure both files are ordered by the same field, e.g., primary key of your records -- it can be achieved by `awk`, for example in case of such input file (sorting key is last number):

```
val1|2
val7|1
```

you can sort entries by `sort -n --field-separator=\| -k 2 1` (see `sort` manpage for explanations of options involved).

Then use `diff` (or similar, if you not on Unix/Linux) utility to create file with different entries.

Comment: What if the database results returned are in a different order from those of the flat file? Even worst if there is no order guaranteed at all on the flat file provided.

Comment: @mtrovo - read the flat file for the key before you retrieve from the DB

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

- Load the results from the database on a Map structure where the key is the Primary Key column and the value is the row itself
- Iterate the flat file collection, search the Map structure based on the primary key and add the differences to a list that will be your output.
- write to the output the differences you previously saved on the list.